# Within Eclipse, Debug configurations for different groups in TestNG

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, testng

How do we setup Eclipse, TestNG (and possibly TestNG-Eclipse plugin?) so that our devs can run two different test configurations conveniently?   We have hundreds of unit tests but only 20 integration tests, so we would prefer to a minimum number of changes to the unit tests if possible.

We have added attributes to our unit tests:

```
// unit tests
@Test

// integration tests
@Test(groups = { "IntegrationTest" })
```

The holy grail would be that we could right-click our package and select either:

```
  debug configuration which only runs unit tests
  debug configuration which the slow running integration tests (and possibly the unit tests).
```

It seems like we could add these configurations to the "Favorites" list.  It is an acceptable compromise.

Finally, the last requirement is that the unit tests will also run on the build server (maven surefire plugin compatible).  This doesn't seem to be a challenge so I'm not too concerned about it.

Also, if there is another framework I should investigate that supports these scenarios, I would also like to hear about that as well.  Right now we are using junit and are exploring TestNG.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a TestNG launch configuration, you can specify various things such as which groups to run.